# how can we calculate gradients for rgb and apply it for sobel

Tags: c#, image-processing, sobel

I am trying to write a sobel filter.I made a gray filter for that and started to write sobel filter but I do not understand some things.I found calculating gx and gy but nobody tells about applying it.What should I do for using them for r,g,b?I am so confused.When I use gradinet(gradient = Math.Abs(gx) + Math.Abs(gy);) should I apply it on a pixel for every r,g,b?I mean if I should do that which way can I use?I could not find any code.By the way when we apply this method matrix is getting smaller.I am so confused about applying this on code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply a sobel filter to an rgb image. Usually you apply it to each of the color channels or you convert the rgb image to grayscale first.

The resulting image of a convolution is always smaller. Either live with it, enlarge your image prior to convolution or after it. There are countless methods to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I saw some codes they are getting used r,g,b( infact they are use 0.59f ,0.3f and so forth I do not understand why they are used for.) after they wrote a gray filter.Am I do not understand something with that?

Comment: how am I supposed to know what you are talking about if you just tell me 2 numbers? maybe they calculate a weigthed sum of r,g,b during convolution which is the same as calculating the convolution of the grayscale image. but if you talk in riddles I can only guess. sorry

Comment: I am sorry you are right.You have been so helpful.At least I learned that sobel can not be applied for r,g,b when we try to write that we use just a channel(through gray filter).Thank you for your help.